# why it is not setting up?

Tags: html, css, tags, sidebar

i am trying to set up side bar
it is not scrolling with content because i have fixed it but if i removes fixed than contents position gets change to downward
any way to set up sidebar without fixing it and attach it with other content

**home.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Home</title>
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css" type="text/css"     rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css"   rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body class="container">
<div>
<h1 style="font-size:65px; text-align:center; height:100px;">Democracy And Destruction</h1>
</div>
<br />
<ul class="sidenav">
<li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
<li><a href="#contact">MyCity</a></li>
<li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="content">
<h2>Rule Your Country</h2>
<p>Paragraph 1........blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah </p>
<p>paragraph 2........blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah </p>
<p>Paragraph 3........blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah </p> 
<h4>Header 4.</h4>
<div>
<ul class="sidenav1">
<li><a class="active" href="#home">Start Playing Now</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/npm.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
</html>
```

**style.css file**

```
@charset "utf-8";
```

body {margin: 0;}

```
ul.sidenav1 {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 15%;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
overflow: auto;
}
ul.sidenav1 li a {
display: block;
color: #000;
padding: 8px 0 8px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}
ul.sidenav1 li a.active {
background-color: #4CAF50;
color: white;
}
ul.sidenav1 li a:hover:not(.active) {
background-color: #555;
color: white;
}
ul.sidenav {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
width: 15%;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
position: fixed;
overflow: auto;
}

ul.sidenav li a {
display: block;
color: #000;
padding: 8px 0 8px 20px;
text-decoration: none;
}

ul.sidenav li a.active {
background-color: #4CAF50;
color: white;
}

ul.sidenav li a:hover:not(.active) {
background-color: #555;
color: white;
}

div.content {
margin-left: 18%;
margin-top:-24px;
padding-top:px;
height: 1200px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
ul.sidenav {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
     text-align: center;
}

div.content {margin-left:0;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px){
ul.sidenav li a {
    text-align: center;
    float: none;
}
}/* CSS Document */
```

Comment: assuming you know why you have added the **bootstrap** framework, I think you shouldn't be asking this !

Comment: i am still **learning bootstrap** i

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try seting um a space on you page for the sidebar, like a div.

```
<body>
    <div class="sidebar">
        <ul>...</ul>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        ...
    </div>
</body>
```

And then have it like:

```
.sidebar{
    position: fixed;
    width: [desired width];
}
.content{
    padding-left: [width of sidebar] //make it a gutter to start your content
}
```

This is not the optimal way though. Just a solution for a simple layout. But what you should really be using is a framework like Bootstrap or Foundation to start and get those simple layouts a easy start.

Answer (score 0):

since you are using bootstrap.. this should work fine

```
 <div class="row">

  <div class="col-sm-3">
   <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
   <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
   <li><a href="#contact">MyCity</a></li>
   <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-9">
   /* body of your webpage */
 </div>
</div>
```